# PHP-FPM is not able to use OCI however PHP is

Tags: php, nginx, oci8, php-7.2, fpm

So I've installed the REMI PHP on RHEL 7. 
It is PHP 7.2
Also included is the Oracle Instant Client. 
I've set the correct LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

When I run php -m it shows the module. oci8.
When see if the module is installed via php Code is says YES via command line and NO via the NGINX/PHP_FPM.

The PDO even says that OCI is a driver on the PHP command line side and not via PHP-FPM on the web.

Not sure what I could be missing.

-R

Comment: maybe your command line and fpm instance have different php.ini files. You could use `php_info()` to determine the correct path to your php.ini

Comment: Usually php-cli runs on a different config

Comment: Usually php-fpm runs on a different config :)

Comment: I'll be back in the office tomorrow so let's see ;)

Comment: Define 'correctly set'.  It's easy to set, but also easy to be set in the wrong place or wrong way and not get propagated to the process.  I'd recommend using ldconfig, as shown in the Instant Client install instructions https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html#ic_x64_inst